# SQL joining two tables and counting

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve all the customers who own more than 1 car.

I have this code:

```
SELECT c.fname, 
       c.lname, 
       c.cid, 
       Count(v.cid) AS nmbrofvehicle 
FROM   customer c 
LEFT JOIN vehicle v 
       ON c.cid = v.cid 
GROUP  BY c.fname;
```

But it returns this error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.cid, count(v.cid) as nmbrofvehicle
from customer c left join vehicle v on c.cid = v.cid 
group by c.fname, c.lname, c.cid
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have there is that you are attempting to group in ungrouped data (e.g. surname).

Some databases (such as MySQL) are very forgiving and try to do this - Oracle, however is not.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.cid
     , a.fname
     , a.sname
     , NVL(b.nmbrofvehicle, 0) AS nmbrofvehicle 
  FROM customers a
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT z.cid
                   , COUNT(z.cid) AS nmbrofvehicle
                FROM vehicle z
               GROUP BY z.cid
            ) b
    ON ( a.cid = b.cid );
```

This will take data from `customers`, and left join any matching data from your `vehicles` table on `cid`, or return 0 thanks to this `NVL` function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `c.cid` from the `select` and add `c.lname` to the `group by`:

```
SELECT c.fname, c.lname, 
       Count(v.cid) AS nmbrofvehicle 
FROM customer c JOIN
     vehicle v 
     ON c.cid = v.cid 
GROUP BY c.fname, c.lname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary because you are requiring at least one match.